# Function of random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have this question:

```
Suppose P(X=0)=1/2 and P(X=8)=1/2. What's the value of E[Y] if Y=(X^2)?
```

So I am having trouble understanding how to go about doing this problem. What I initially tried was doing the expected value of X and then just squaring that solution. So I did:

```
E[x] = 0*(1/2) + 8*(1/2) = 4
```

so for E[Y] I just did 4^2 to get 16. This is not the answer though, and I am cnow lost as to how to proceed.

Comment: What are the possible values of $Y$? With what probabilities are they taken on?

Comment: (1/2)^2? I am not sure to be honest

Comment: If $X=0$ then $Y=0$. If $X=8$, then $Y=64$.

Comment: So then I would go about doing the same thing? I would do 0*(1/2) + 64(1/2) = 32?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tell a story. It involves Xavier and Yolande. A referee flips a fair coin. If the result is heads, then Xavier gets $0$ dollars. If the result is tails, then Xavier gets $8$ dollars.

Let random variable $X$ be the amount of money Xavier gets. What is the "average value" (mean) of $X$? Well, Xavier gets $0$ dollars with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and $8$ dollars with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus
$$E(X)=0\cdot\frac{1}{2}+8\cdot \frac{1}{2}.$$

Yolande gets the *square* of what Xavier gets. If random variable $Y$ is the amount of money she gets, then $Y=X^2$. What is the mean of $Y$?

With probability $\frac{1}{2}$, Yolande gets $0^2$ dollars. with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, Yolande gets $8^2$ dollars. Thus
$$E(Y)=0^2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+8^2\cdot \frac{1}{2}.$$